# Matlab displaying all representable numbers

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, floating-point, binary

Today our teacher taught us about how numbers are represented in the computer, and he programmed a Matlab function that gets the minimum exponent, maximum exponent, and the number of bits in our system, and displays all representable numbers in our system.

for example:
when minimum exponent is -1, maximum exponent is 1, and we work in 2 bit system

```
f(-1,1,2)

ans =

    0.5000
    0.6250
    0.7500
    0.8750
    1.0000
    1.2500
    1.5000
    1.7500
    2.0000
    2.5000
    3.0000
    3.5000
```

But I truly don't understand the code he wrote. I would love if someone could explain to me. His basic idea is to represent the binary numbers (00,01,10,11) in a matrix, and then multiply that matrix by a vector, and I completely lost him, and can't understand his code.

this is what he wrote:

```
%% Computing the Matrix A
m = 2^p;
A = zeros(m,p);
for i=1:p
   temp = [zeros(m/2^i,1); ones(m/2^i,1)];
   A(:,i) = repmat(temp,2^(i-1),1);
end


%% Computing the numbers
V = zeros(p,1);
for i=1:p 
    V(i) = 1/2^i;
end
N = zeros((emax-emin+1)*2^p,1);
k=1;
for e = emin:emax
    N(k:k+2^p-1) = 2^e*A*V+2^e*ones(2^p,1);
    k = k + 2^p;
end
 sort(N)
```

Comment: Best way to understand new code is to use breakpoints. Have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in fact 3 bits because there is an implied leading one:

example: `1.75 = 2^0 + 2^-1 + 2^-2`

So your numbers are formed of a significand with implied leading 1 + 2 bits b1 b2:

```
1.b1b2 = 1 + b1/2 + b2/4
```

multyplied by the base (2) raised to the exponent e, so finally

```
(1 + b1/2 + b2/4) * 2^e
```

The code used to form all the combinations is un-necessarily complex.

All the possible significands could just be formed like this:

```
significands = 1 + (0:2^p-1)/2^p;
```

Then all the exponents:

```
exponents = 2.^(emin:emax);
```

Then all the numbers:

```
floats = significands' * exponents;
floats = floats(:);
```

Instead of that, the first loop form all possible bit combinations column by column (1 combination per row, there are 2^p rows).

Lets take p=3 as an example: the values of first bit are `[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]'`

Then the values of second bit `[0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]'`

Then the values of third bit `[0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]'`

When you put these columns together, you get the 8 possible combinations of 3 bits:

```
[ 0 0 0 ;
  0 0 1 ;
  0 1 0 ;
  0 1 1 ;
  1 0 0 ;
  1 0 1 ;
  1 1 0 ;
  1 1 1 ]
```

The second loop just form the vector `[2^-1 2^-2 ... 2^-p]'` which are the multipliers for each of these columns

The third loop perform the multiplication for each exponent (notice the second term that adds the leading one, multiplied by 2^e).